# backbone js. compare dates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, date-format

Im working on an underscore.js template in backbone. In the template i receive to dates in unix time. I convert them to a date by multiply them by 1000.

In a loop im trying to compare them. i Want to check how many days its betweeen them.
I want to be able to print different html depending on if the difference between the dates is more or less than 5 days.

So if less than 5 days ago it got uploaded i want to print some html. If not i want to print some other html.

How would i do that? Anyone that know?

```
<% collection.each(function(model,index) { 

    var a = moment(new Date(model.get("uploaded_date")*1000)); /*represents when the item got uploaded/approved*/
    var b = moment(new Date(now)*1000); /*represents the server time*/
    var diff = b.diff(a, 'days');

    %>

    <div class="content">
        <% if(diff<5) { %>

            /*doesn't work*/

        <% } %>   
    </div>

<% }); %>
```

Comment: What does console.log(diff) give you ?

Comment: Its supposed to give me the diff between "a" and "b" in days.(number).
Like 1,5 or 7 etc. And it does. But its a bit off. where it should give me 2 i get 1. eg: if "approved" is set to the date two days ago i get one. And i also get one if its set to yesterday.

Comment: dont put login in your templates, create a method on your model, or a helper function.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong : ehh?

Comment: @RoyMJ I mean.. the template should be as dummy as possible, i'd have created a method on the model and called it from the template `<% if model.olderThan(5) { %>` is cleaner that way.. and easier to make a unit test n_n

Comment: I would do that if i could. The thing is tho that the model dont have the current server time. And i cant put that one in the model.

Comment: @user3122094 then pass the server time as a parameter to the model method `olderThan: function(days, reference_date){}` make the `reference_date` optional if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var b = moment(new Date(now*1000)); /*represents the server time*/
```

instead of :

```
var b = moment(new Date(now)*1000); /*represents the server time*/
```

By default, moment#diff will return number rounded down. If you want the floating point number, pass true as the third argument :

```
var diff = b.diff(a, 'days', true);
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have the same problem with comparing the dates tho.

Comment: The problem is that i want to print how many days its between the two dates. And check if its more or less than 5 days between them. I also need to turn it around a bit. If its 0 days between the dates the item should be "active" for 5 days. and if its 5 days between them the idem should get "inactive". (different classes i add).

Comment: can you add the values of 'model.get("uploaded_date")' and 'now' ?

Comment: Sure, i get them like this

Wed Jan 22 2014 10:57:00 GMT+0100
Wed Jan 22 2014 11:17:33 GMT+0100

Comment: I have created a test here http://jsfiddle.net/PNx7D/ and it's working as expected.

Comment: the difference between this two dates is 1 not 2 as you are waiting, am I right ?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/PNx7D/1/. If you edit the dates, you have the behaviour you want. By the way you don't need the 'new Date()' as in the exemple.